# NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: differs from actual Label height

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, uitableview, height

So here how it goes: I'm implementing a UITableView (grouped style, with 1 section) with standard UITableViewCells (style - UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle) as content.
My textLabel.text can be really long, that's why I set some params in TableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:CELL_FONT_SIZE];
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

To resize the cell height I've implemented tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: as follows:

```
Test *test = (Test *)[self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = test.test_name;

UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:CELL_FONT_SIZE];

CGFloat horizontalConstraint;
if (self.bagdePresent)
{
    // there will be big badge!
    horizontalConstraint = 250.0f;
} else
{
    // there will NO badge
    horizontalConstraint = 280.0f;
}

CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(horizontalConstraint, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// return label height, 20 as gap, 30 for rating image,
return labelSize.height + 20 + 30;
```

First I check if there will be badge image in the cell, if so, I reduce horizontal space available.

And here's the problem (finally): for some strings (some string lengths) sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: returns value that is less than real cell's textLabel height when I set its text property to the same string. As a result some if the cells have textLabels bigger than cell's bounds. When I add\remove some words to\from the string which displayed wrong, sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: gives exact height which is later confirmes with textLabel actual height.

I thought it might be a problem with font, but as you see the font is the same. 
Where to dig from here? ;)

**UPD1:**
Here's an example of textLabel being taller than it was calculated in heightForRowAtIndexPath:
[image: tall textLabel]

[image: Normal textLabel with longer text]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to take advantage of `sizeToFit`. First you set the width of your label to your `horizontalConstraint`, then you call `[cell.textLabel sizeToFit]` (that will adjust the height of the label to fit it's content but leave the width as you set it (almost - that means it might become a little narrower):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat horizontalConstraint;
    if (self.bagdePresent)
    {
        // there will be big badge!
        horizontalConstraint = 250.0f;
    } else
    {
        // there will NO badge
        horizontalConstraint = 280.0f;
    }

    Test *test = (Test *)[self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = test.test_name;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.text = test.test_name;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:CELL_FONT_SIZE];           
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.font = cellFont;

    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    frame.size.width = horizontalConstraint;
    label.frame = frame;
    [label sizeToFit];

    CGSize labelSize = label.frame.size;

    // return label height, 20 as gap, 30 for rating image,
    return labelSize.height + 20 + 30;
}
```

Comment: Tobi, thanks for the suggestion, but calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: from heightForRowAtIndexPath: creates infinite loop: i'm trying to get a cell, before returning it, TableView wants to get its height... I was thinking about another way of getting the cell from heightForRowAtIndexPath:, but found no solution.. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: I didn't think of that. I've edited my answer. Just create a new `UILabel`, set it's properties and get the height from it.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, cell behaves as before. The funny thing is that there's some marginal text length which causes this problem. On the pictures you can see, that when I add some chars to the cell text, it starts to render OK (the same happens when I remove some chars from it). Not sure where to go next...

Comment: So I kind of "solved" this by modifying the constraint values, it works somehow now. But I will meet the same problem when I start to adopt the code to device orientation change ;)